# Put a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell's AccessoryView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, subview, accessoryview

I am experimenting with putting a `UITextField` inside a `UITableViewCell`.

Now I got two working methods.

Using `addSubview` method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"textFieldCell"];

UITextField *textFieldView = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 7, 150, 30)];
[textFieldView setPlaceholder:@"Placeholder"];

[cell addSubview:textFieldView];
```

Using `setAccessoryView` method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"textFieldCell"];

UITextField *textFieldView = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)];
[textFieldView setPlaceholder:@"Placeholder"];

[cell setAccessoryView:textFieldView];
```

In my opinion the `setAccessoryView` result is better looking, since the alignment is done automatically.

But my question is: It it ok to put a `UITextField` inside a `AccessoryView`? Or is there a good reason why I shouldn't do it that way?

Comment: I tried the `accessoryView` way but couldn't widen the `textField` when loading the `tableView` in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any restriction on it by apple, but main intention to add `accessoryView` property in `UITableViewCell` class, to be used, typically as a control, on the right side of the cell (normal state).

Following sentence taken from the apple [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

If the value of this property is not nil, the UITableViewCell class uses the given view for the accessory view in the table view’s normal (default) `enter code here`state; it ignores the value of the `accessoryType` property. **The provided accessory view can be a framework-provided control or label or a custom view.** The accessory view appears in the right side of the cell.

According to this statement you can provide`UITextField` (framework-provided control) as `accessoryView`.

Comment: So what I understand is the following: It isn't bad, but it isn't pretty either.

Comment: It can be pretty as per your client requirement and there is no restriction from apple so go on from me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's restricted. But the accessoryView has a role in the design: to show that the cell has interactive options.
If you want to do it the correct way, you should append UIViews in cell.contentView.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but didn't Apple also put `UISwitch` controls inside the Settings screen using `accessoryView`?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.. Didn't see the source code. But maybe you're right. As I said there is no restriction in HIG. But if I want my cell to be flexible and easily modified, I wouldn't rely on accessoryView.

Comment: "I'm not sure about that" err, well they're all over the Settings app: http://cl.ly/image/3A2z0l2x0n1H