# Align Custom UITableViewCell content with Header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am creating a Table View with Static Cells. Some of the cells need a Custom Style because the contain a label on the left and a text field on the right.

I want to align the label on the left with the header of the section like the Basic cell style does but I can not find a way to do this.

Here is what my app currently looks:

[image: My App]

Here ist what the aligned labels in the Basic style look like:

[image: System Preferences]

I am using Auto Layout with Size Classes and Constraints.

Comment: Are you setting frame in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: no, should I do that?

Comment: Yah, I guess. Its not a best way to solve it. But once I have done this kind of thing as I didn't find any solution.
Also only setting frame will not work in Autolayout mode, It may not change the frame of view sometimes.

try setting `cell.titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;` 
for the view you want to change position.
Alternatively also try to find it using autolayout, if there is any way?
And tell me if you found it.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help, it seems like this has been resolved automatically by Xcode 6.3

Comment: I found another good post about that topic: http://coffee-coding.com/ios7-vs-ios8-margin-constraints-differ/

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar issue once.

My requirement were,

1) To create a tableview which has a header and cells.

2) The header will have 3 labels, under those labels the cell will hold the corresponding data for the respective labels in the header.

To achieve above requirement I framed my labels in header and based on the labels position and size in the header I reframed the cell's labels according to header labels.

I implemented the above thing in TableView's delegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and reframed each cell's labels based on the header's position and size inside it.

For example -

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
         // customize the cell just before it will be displayed

         // access section header
         UIView *sectionHeader = [tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];

         // access section header label
         UILabel *headerLeftLabel = (UILabel *)[sectionHeader viewWithTag:HEADER_LABEL_TAG];

         // access cell's corresponding label which is to be aligned as the header's above label 
         UILabel *leftCellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_LABEL_TAG];

         // align/ reframe the cells label with the corresponding label in the header
         [leftCellLabel setFrame: headerLeftLabel.frame];

         // similar for other labels

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely be able to use a `basic` / `default` UITableViewCell style, then set a Text Field as the cell's `accessoryView`.

Using the `basic` style will automatically line up the section header and the text in each cell.

[Put a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell's AccessoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683773/put-a-uitextfield-inside-a-uitableviewcells-accessoryview)

Answer (score 0):

The leading space of section header or system defined `Right Detail` style cell, is different under different screen orientations. It's 16 points under portraint mode, and 20 points under landscape mode. While the trailing space of the `Detail` label, is constantly 15 points.

Currently what I did is to create outlets for the leading anchor constraints of each views in the custom cells, and change their constants in the following method:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();
    // 16 in portrait mode, and 20 in landscape mode, act as the baseline
    let spacing = titleLabelOfRightDetailCell.frame.origin.x; 
    // leadingAnchorConstraints is an array of views within custom table view cells that need to be left aligned
    for constraint in leadingAnchorConstraints {
        constraint.constant = spacing;
    }
}
```

This way I can make sure all table view cells are left aligned, either in portrait mode or landscape mode.

EDIT:

Found a more elegant solution: [Matching left alignment of custom & standard UITableViewCell types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349917/matching-left-alignment-of-custom-standard-uitableviewcell-types)

Answer (score 0):

please look at the following post. [Matching left alignment of custom & standard UITableViewCell types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349917/matching-left-alignment-of-custom-standard-uitableviewcell-types) The problem and solution is outlined

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I did the follows:

In my custom UITableViewCell I added the `layoutSubviews` function as follows:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  contentView.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(self.indentationLevel), y: 0, width: (self.frame.width - 2 * CGFloat(self.indentationLevel)), height: self.frame.height)
}
```

And in `cellForRowAt` I did it like this:

```
cell.indentationLevel = 20
```